# How to catch events triggered by out-of-the-box component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

Is it possible to catch events triggered by standard component?
For example click even on tab for component like "The Featured Topics & Feeds component".
Or on "Navigation Menu" component.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `https://<myDomain>.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app`

Click on `Event`

You can see many kinds of events that you can use here

Click on `Force`

You can see tab events and others:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I do know about tab events. But How to catch those events when event is triggered by Standard component, like those that I've mentioned?? I custom component I have access to .cmp file and can add controller method call on onclick event. But for standard component, provided by Salesforce there is no access to .cmp file and onclick event the same way. . .

Comment: I am not sure, try adding an event handler: `<aura:handler event="force:tabFocused" action="{!c.tabFocusedAction}" />`

Comment: But in which .cmp file I can add it? There is no access to .cmp file for Standard component provided by Salesforce. I am a beginner in SF development. What I am missing? Thank you

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. I though you wanted to listen to a standard event from your lightning component

Comment: Thank you for replying. I need to listen to any event in "Standard Component" provided by SF. SF provides me with "The Featured Topics & Feeds component". and "Navigation Menu" component, for example. When you create Community, these components are part of Napili template already.  I need to catch events generated by these/similar components. And, it seems, there is No access to .cmp code of these "standard components".  Am I correct? Is there way to catch events of those components? Many thanks

Comment: 1. there is no access to the standard components. 2. you say that you need to catch the standard events - where (which technology...) are you planning to do that?

Comment: First of all: many thanks for replying to me. I really appreciate your time. We have SF Communities built using Community templates (like Napili).  We try to find way to call Google Analytics when user clicks on buttons, tabs, etc that are located on those provided-by-Salesforce templates(to collect some analytics). Those buttons (etc) are out-of-the-box (standard) SF components. We know by now how to call Google Analytics from custom components. But, to do the same with out-of-the-box components, we need access to the events.

Comment: MORE: I looked at Google Tag Manager that seems to allow to catch events, but code-snippet needs to be copied into 'body' tag of Community to integrate with GTM, and I can not find any way to do that. At this point I'm stuck. So many thanks for any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: I still do not understand what technology / code do you use to try and catch these events? do you use lightning components? if so, please share the code you have. If not - what exactly are you planning to use?